# override equals in a java set

Tags: java, equals, hashset

How do I prevent a set from containing duplicate arrays?

```
    Set<int[]> set = new HashSet<>();
    int[] tmp = new int[]{1,2};
    set.add(tmp);
    tmp = new int[]{1,2};
    set.add(tmp);
    System.out.println(set.size());
```

I'd like the set to contain only one element.

Comment: Use an `ArrayList<Integer>` instead of an `int[]`. Or implement your own wrapper class that contains an int array and then you can override `hashCode` and `equals`

Comment: I think there may be a deeper architectural issue here, why are you adding int arrays (as opposed to a custom datatype) to a `Set`?

Comment: You can [wrap each array in an IntBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/IntBuffer.html#wrap(int%5B%5D)), since IntBuffer provides meaningful equals and hashCode methods.  (Just don’t change the position or limit of any of the buffers after they’re created.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `TreeSet`.

`TreeSet` uses `Comparable.compareTo()` or `Comparator.compare()` instead of `hashCode()` and `equals()` to compare elements. It can be specified in the constructor.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<int[]> set = new TreeSet<>(Arrays::compare);
    set.add(new int[]{1,2});
    set.add(new int[]{1,2});
    System.out.println(set.size());
}
```

output:

```
1
```

`Arrays::compare` is a `Comparator` that compares arrays in lexicographical order.